# Addon toolbar - create button to show back button history?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a toolbar and want to create a button that will display a drop down list of the back button history which the user can select and go back to that page.

Comment: This button already exists... it is the back button ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Firefox source to see how it's implemented. Open source and all that.

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.xul#507

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/